# JW Player Flex integration

Tags: apache-flex, jwplayer

I have a Data Grid that contains a list of videos. When a video is selected by the user, i would like to display it in jwplayer.

I have succeded to integrate JW Player within my flex app using this example : http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Embedding_JW_Player_Version_5_into_Flex-16707.html

the problem is that i'm not able to change the source file. Here's my code :

```
myDg_selectionChangeHandler(event:GridSelectionEvent) :void{
   video_source= myDg.selectedItem.url; 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for JWPlayer sources?
http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/#Sourcecode

Comment: No. I just can't switch between multiple videos, because i want to use the Flex Data Grid as a manual playlist. So when the user change the selection, i would like to be able to play the selected video in the player